# How to translate a "tight sequence" to spanish?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, mathematical-spanish

Not a mathematical question as such, but I wouldn't trust the translations given in any other community.

Let $\{\mathbb{P}_n\}$ be a family of proability measures in $(\mathbb{R^d}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d))$. Then the family is $\textbf{tight}$ if for every epsilon $\epsilon >0$, there exists an interval $(a,b]$ such that $\mathbb{P}_n((a,b]^c)\leq \epsilon$ for all $n$.

I want to translate this definition to spanish and I thought maybe using "una familia estrecha" could work. However 1) It sounds funny and 2) then I will also need to define a stochastic differential equation in the $\textbf{narrow}$ sense, which in my head it also translates as "estrecho". Any suggestions on how can I differentiate this two concepts?

Comment: In some translations of Russian text I've seen the term "sucesión ajustada de medidas". In translations of English works, I have seen the rather flamboyant name of "sucesiones uniformemente acotadas". Some Spanish (from Spain) authors use the later; on the opposite side of the Atlantic (the Americas) the use the former is more common; some even talk about "sucesiones apretada, tensa o ajustada de medidas".